# How to make a string visible on a webpage using Django form fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a django page I've created and managed to pass values to it.
I am trying to make a text box which would contain some string.
this string can be edited and saved by the user if needed.

views.py

```
form = EditProjectForm(project_name = project_name,store_id=store_id, `enter code here`start_date=start_date,end_date=end_date,data = request.POST or None)
context = {'someList': someList ,'form':form}
return render(request, 'editview.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class EditProjectForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.project_name = kwargs.pop('project_name')
    super(EditProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['project_name'] = forms.CharField(self.project_name)
```

I tried using

```
forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': self.project_name }))
```

But that does not show up as editable text.

I would like self.project_name to be visible on my page in a text box and be editable.

this is what I would want the output to look like

[image: desired output]

EDIT 1 :
I used itzmeontv tip to use 'initial'
Thanks for the 'initial'
However, it seems to work only when I am not passing arguments when creating the form

For example. 
form = EditProjectForm() in my views.py seems to work, 
but 
form = EditProjectForm(project_name = project_name) 
and then setting 
initial = self.project_name , does not work.

EDIT 2  :
USing form = EditProjectForm(initial={'project_name': project_name})
seemd to work.
Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

Try this with `initial`

```
forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': self.project_name }), initial=self.project_name)
```

**OR**

```
form = EditProjectForm(#your arguments, initial={'project_name': self.project_name})
```

Comment: However, 
it seems to work only when I am not passing arguments when creating the form
For ex. EditProjectForm() 
seems

Comment: For ex. 
form = EditProjectForm() in my views.py seems to work, but 
form = EditProjectForm(project_name = project_name) and then setting initial = self.project_name , does not work.